# Fuse cc to Blender 2.8 flipped normal issue

Tags: faces, normals, versions

i am having an issue with importing Fuse characters i make, when i import the obj file into blender 2.79b/ue4/paint3d the model looks fine, when in 2.8 the normals are all out of wack wondering if this is a bug, if i export it, fbx or obj, the changes carry over into other programs 2.79b included.
i have included an image of whats happening, on the left is 2.8 on the right is 2.79b. a big thank you to anyone who can help me with this issue

[image]

Answer (score 3):

All you gotta do is disable *Show Backface* in settings of every material, and it will look perfect.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I have this issue. When I export from fuse into mixamo then into blender it works fine.

My fix for this is to delete the nodes and add image node into material output node and then choose the image from the obj mtl file

Complicated but only work around I have

Comment: Changing forward and/or up does not work?

Answer (score 0):

For each material go to settings and change the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Hashed*

Answer (score 0):

I made a video tutorial about fixing material issues when importing an Adobe Fuse CC character into Blender: https://youtu.be/I0luYBTXTEg

Also, in this other tutorial I show how to remove makeup/eyelashes from an Adobe Fuse CC character in Blender: https://youtu.be/hYjrkz5Nj4c

Hope it helps :)

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/what-is-wrong-about-answering-with-a-link

Comment: A tutorial is more useful and intuitive than a thousand comments here. I had the problem of the material as well and, in addiction to the fact that a video is more intuitive, nobody have time to read a lot of comments - especially if they have to work and deliver products quickly

Comment: Consider it more a heads up as to why this answer may be closed in review, as often happens to answers on SE that rely solely on links.(No matter how good the content of the link) May find this of interest https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10000-hour-rule-wrong-really-master-skill/   Particularly the "Learning Pyramid".